# Self-hosted collaborative document editor

Tags: wysiwyg, text-editor

I'm looking for something like Google Documents, but that our company can host ourselves (for security/confidentiality reasons).

I'd like something where multiple users can edit a word-processing-like document from the web. Ideally it would be able to show the history of revisions, and maybe compare them. Wiki software doesn't really fit the bill, since the syntax is too complicated for some users.

Does this exist?

Comment: It's a long shot, but SharePoint definitely supports these things

Answer (score 1):

Here are two completely opposite but not quite perfect answers:

1. [Google Apps for Business](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html) Ultimately this is hosted on Google's servers, but theoretically security issues are adequately handled.  This is still a tough sell in some businesses.
2. [Etherpad](http://etherpad.org)  This is an open source, web based, real-time, collaborative document editor.  Apparently this was bought by Google, and was supposed to be merged with Google Wave, but instead it seems that they spun it off as an open source project.  It looks neat and can be locally hosted, but it seems a little bleeding edge.

There's another product [BeWeeVee](http://www.beweevee.com/Partners.aspx) that's in the Windows world .NET/Silverlight. as well.

And I'm sure there are other -- maybe better solutions.